# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The below login view generates the token but the profile view says, user is not authenticated.

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

            login(request, user)
            # login(request, user)
            request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Token ' + token.key
            return redirect('myprofile:profile')
            # return Response({"token": token.key})
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials'})

class ProfileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({'username': user.username, 'email': user.email})
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'User is not authenticated'})
```

I tried on postman and sent the token and there it worked, but I don't know why the code is not working on my end within the browser.

Comment: Could you also share the payloads you are trying to parse?

Comment: You're probably not passing in the token on your second request.

Comment: Because here you applied ```TokenAuthentication``` so Django Rest Framework browsable  not supported Token based auth you need to apply ```BasicAuthentication``` or ```SessionAuthentication``` play with browser

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not enabled the correct authentication classes.

In your `settings.py` file, configure `REST_FRAMEWORK` as follows

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

You still need to log in within your browser. Set up a login page if you haven't.